# Realm iOS relationship from mysql json results

Tags: ios, relationship, realm

I want to use  `Realm`  to my iOS app but I have a problem with the relationship. What I want to achieve is a relationship between the following two  `RLMobjects` :

```
class Catalogue: RLMObject {

     dynamic var ID = ""
     dynamic var greekName = ""
     dynamic var deutschName = ""
     dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
     dynamic var updatedAt = NSDate()

     override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}

class Products: RLMObject {

     dynamic var foodName = ""
     dynamic var foodDescription = ""
     dynamic var foodPrice = ""
     dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
     dynamic var updatedAt = NSDate()

     dynamic var category: Catalogue?
}
```

I am retrieving all my data from a server in  `JSON`  format and the problem is that

> I can not set the category as relationship to Catalogue ID.

In my database the category field is a foreign key to the Catalogue ID.

> Does anyone knows how can I do that in Realm?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing the Catalogue ID in the `dynamic var category: Catalogue?` relationship field you will need to find the Catalogue object and just store that directly. This is how you link objects and is an important and powerful part of using NoSQL type DB's like Realm.

I would also add an array of `products` relationship on Catalogue so that you can link all the products to the Catalogue itself.

You can see more discussion about this [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1741) if that wasn't fully clear. Hope this helps

Comment: Can you please give me a code example?  I read also the link but it is not so clear for me. The only way to set the `category`, which is the `Catalogue ID` is as `String` and i don't have any relation.

Comment: Let's say you have CatalogueID = 47. First you would need to get that catalog object `let catalogObject = Realm().objectForPrimaryKey(Catalogue.self, CatalogueID: "47")` Then you can take one of your products `let product = Product()` and do `product.catagory = catalogObject`. Now when you store `product` it will be linked to the proper category. Notice the link is made by linking the objects directly, not by a foreign_key. Let me know if this was clear

Comment: Ok about the linking I get it. I get the category id from my database as a number. To be honest I can not understand how can i link this number to the `Catalague`. I can give you a Json result `{
        "category_id" = 2;
        "created_at" = "2015-08-16 17:51:40";
        "food_description" = "Hausgemachtes Knoblauchbrot";
        name = Skordopsomo;
        price = "2,50";
        "updated_at" = "2015-08-16 17:51:40";
    }
` How can i link to that `category_id`? What i want to do is to read it from the Json result and then create the relationship to the `Catalogue.ID`.

Comment: Ok thank you  @ yoshyosh for your help. I fixed it depending on your example but in the new Swift i used it like this `let catalogueObject = Catalogue(forPrimaryKey: products["category_id"] as! String)`. Now i have to learn how to make the query depending on this relationship.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that! Great so if you want to get all products in that catalogue, you can just do `Realm().objects(Products).filter("category = %@", catalogueObject)`. If it's the same Catalogue object that had a `category_id` of 2, this will return all the products that belong to that catalogue.

Comment: One more thing, notice how you are fetching the `catalogueObject` with `products["category_id"]`? If you already have the `products` and you linked the catalogue to it, all you would need to do is `products.catalogue` and you have your object. Linking your objects makes things more straightforward once everything is set up

Comment: thank you very much for your help everything works now depending on your suggestions.